# Going around generic typecasting warning

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to get around an unchecked typecast warning that java gives when I use generics. I searched around and I'm currently using a workaround, but it seems to be really slow and inefficient. Any good way to go around the warning?

My original code:

```
Message<DataPoint> msg = (Message<DataPoint>) in.readObject();
km.points = msg.payload;
```

The workaround:

```
Message<?> msg = null;
Object obj = in.readObject();
if (obj instanceof Message) {
    msg = (Message<?>) obj;
    if (msg.payload instanceof ArrayList<?>) {
        if (msg.payload.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < msg.payload.size(); i++) {
                Object o = msg.payload.get(i);
                if (o instanceof DataPoint) {
                    km.points.add((DataPoint)o);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `in.readObject` only returns `Object` and you can't change the API, but you can **prove** that it will always contain an instance of `Message`, then there shouldn't be any problems.  The warning is there so that you get a sense that this *might* not be type safe, but if you can prove it is, then don't worry too much about it.

Comment: Why not use @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")?

Answer (score 0):

Warnings are just that, warnings and shouldn't stop you from compiling. If you do not want the warning to appear however you can annotate the method with:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```